# Wordpress logo upload option in theme panel

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello every one i am facing one issue in adding logo option in my theme panel of wordpress i am using this code

```
function logo_display()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="logo" /> 
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
   <?php
}
function handle_logo_upload()
{
    if(!empty($_FILES["demo-file"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
        $temp = $urls["url"];
       return $temp;   
    }  
    return $option;
}
function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
    add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");
    add_settings_field("logo", "Logo", "logo_display", "theme-options", "section");  
    register_setting("section", "logo", "handle_logo_upload");
}
add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

The issue is its not saving logo and also not displaying it in admin as well.
I have tried this 10 times with different ways but this code is not working. Please look in this code and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add else condition in your " handle_logo_upload " function. Try following code:

```
function logo_display()
{
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="ologo" value="<?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>" readonly /><input type="file" name="logo" id="imgupload" style="display: none;" />
  <a id="OpenImgUpload" class="button button-primary">Image Upload</a>
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
   <?php
}
function handle_logo_upload()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["logo"]) && !empty($_FILES['logo']['name']))
    {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
        $temp = $urls["url"];
       return $temp;
    }
 elseif(isset($_FILES["logo"]) && empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])){
  $urls = $_POST["ologo"];
  return $urls;
 }
   return $option;
} 
function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
    add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");
    add_settings_field("logo", "Logo", "logo_display", "theme-options", "section");  
    register_setting("section", "logo", "handle_logo_upload");
}
add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try this. May this will help you.

https://kwight.ca/2012/12/02/adding-a-logo-uploader-to-your-wordpress-site-with-the-theme-customizer/

Comment: I am making a theme option panel without any frame work so i need a option there i have used this and this function is creating option in Theme customizer